# Unhook the comment form in Buddypress

Tags: functions, hooks, buddypress

Im trying unhook the comment form found in the functions.php of the deafault buddypress theme so I can change it a bit. I placed this piece of code into my child theme functions.php but it didn't change anything. What did I do wrong?

```
remove_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'bp_dtheme_comment_form', 10 );
if ( !function_exists( 'my_dtheme_comment_form' ) ) :
function my_dtheme_comment_form( $default_labels ) {
global $user_identity;

$commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();
$req = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
$aria_req = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '' );
$fields =  array(
    'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Name', 'buddypress' ) . ( $req ? '<span class="required"> *</span>' : '' ) . '</label> ' .
                '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
    'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email', 'buddypress' ) . ( $req ? '<span class="required"> *</span>' : '' ) . '</label> ' .
                '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
    'url'    => '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website', 'buddypress' ) . '</label>' .
                '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" /></p>',
);

$new_labels = array(
    'comment_field'  => '<p class="form-textarea"><textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="60" rows="10" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>',
    'fields'         => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', $fields ),
    'logged_in_as'   => '',
    'must_log_in'    => '<p class="alert">' . sprintf( __( 'You must be <a href="%1$s">logged in</a> to post a comment.', 'buddypress' ), wp_login_url( get_permalink() ) ) . '</p>',
    'title_reply'    => __( '', 'buddypress' )
);

return apply_filters( 'my_dtheme_comment_form', array_merge( $default_labels, $new_labels ) );
}
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'my_dtheme_comment_form', 10 );
endif;
```

To test that nothing changed I removed the label text for 'title_reply'

Comment: Kindly provide the context in which the form is hooked in the original functions.php, the original filter has most probably not been added at that stage yet, wrap it in an 'init', 999 action, or later.

Comment: Hmmm I don't know what you mean by context. All I did was copy the function and paste it to my functions.php and then I changed the function name on the add_filter to my.

Comment: The [`remove_filter` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter) has to be used with the exact same arguments that the filter was added with. You said you have a child theme, so the parent theme contains and `add_filter` somewhere, you have to remove it with the exact same arguments (priority, numargs) to actually remove it. Find `add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'bp_dtheme_comment_form' ... )` and make sure it's got the same exact arguments that you're using to remove. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I had already done that. You can see it at the top of the code above. That's why I'm confused it's not working.

Comment: ...again, the `remove_filter` function has to be used with the _SAME_ exact arguments that the filter was added with. Meaning that if the filter was added like this: `add_filter( 'tag', 'function', 12, 3 );` it should be removed with `remove_filter( 'tag', 'function', 12, 3 );` - the _exact same_ arguments have to be used. It will not be removed otherwise. So are you sure that your remove function matches the add function in the parent theme?

Comment: "__Important: To remove a hook, the $function_to_remove and $priority arguments must match when the hook was added. This goes for both filters and actions. No warning will be given on removal failure.__" have you made sure?

Comment: I mean unless I'm missing something right in front of my face Im positive it's the exact same function. The form has 3 functions total in the buddypress default functions.php and pasted them all in my functions.php and added the proper remove_action and none of them worked.

Comment: Show us the original `add_filter` for that function in the parent theme; that's what I've been asking for. I'm sure the original hook function is the same, but is the priority of the original hook you're removing really 10?

Comment: yeap I copy and pasted it `add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'bp_dtheme_comment_form', 10 )`

Comment: Still havent gotten anywhere with this.

Comment: Have you made sure that your callback has been added to the filters stack? wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/02/16/inside-wordpress-actions-filters/ it's time for you to start debugging with `var_dump` and `exit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - I didn't realize wordpress overwrites the functions in the default theme if I place them in my child theme functions.php. So all I had to do was paste them into my functions.php and edit how I want them.

Answer (score 0):

Better,

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_bp_comment_filter' );
function remove_bp_comment_filter() {
    remove_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'bp_dtheme_comment_form', 10 );
    remove_action( 'comment_form_top', 'bp_dtheme_before_comment_form' );
    remove_action( 'comment_form', 'bp_dtheme_after_comment_form' );
}
```